# Data acquisition from Pins ( 5Volt)

Tags: voltage, data, computer

I'm trying to creat a data acquisition system using:

- computer
- Geosig ve-53
- KPci3101

from the seismic sensor's [manual](http://www.geosig.com/productfile2.html?productid=10324) we can see that every pin's output is a 5 volt (or 10?), my question is, how can i know the velocity of the vibration since the output will be the same?
( I'm not a physicist )

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It is a digital data so it's always 5V, it would output different patterns of 1's and 0's, you have to interpret these

Comment: @Qmechanic you might be right

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition i think i got the idea now 
everytime i'll get a different 1 and 0 combination and it's up to me to interpret it into a spectrograms.